# Flutter: AudioPlayers how to stop multiple sounds at once?

Tags: flutter, dart

I use AudioPlayers package.

I have Button1 that plays the sounds. (Code Below)

```
  AudioCache playerCache = new AudioCache(); // you already initialized this

  AudioPlayer player = new AudioPlayer();

  void _playFile(String yol, String name) async {
    player = await playerCache.play(yol);
  }
```

But there is another button which calling "Button2" has to stop all of the sounds at once. I wrote this :

```
void cancelPlay() {
    print("stop");
    playSounds.removeRange(0, playSounds.length);
    player.stop();
    player.stop();
  }
```

However , when user click Button2 , it only stops the last sound. I want that to stop all of the sounds. How to do that ?

I guess The problem is, that every time i call _playFile() (press Button 1) a new instance of AudioPlayer is assigned to the player variable, hence in cancelPlay() the player variable holds only the last instance of AudiPlayer.

How can i do to store the instances in a list.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure with the package, but did you try something like with `List`: `players.add(await playerCache.play(yol));`, so you could `stop` every instance individually?

Answer (score 2):

make a variable

`List<AudioPlayer> audioPlayers = [];`

every time you tap button1, add new audioPlayer

`audioPlayers.add(new AudioPlayer());`

then when you tap on button2, do something like this to stop every audioPlayer

```
audioPlayers.forEach((audioPlayer) => audioPlayer.stop());
```

or even better would be function to toggle the AudioPlaybackState of audioPlayers, so if they are paused then play and vice versa. Ofcourse this example is based on presumption that every audioPlayer controller has same AudioPlaybackState as first:

```
void toggleAudioPlayers() {
    if (audioPlayers.first.playbackState == AudioPlaybackState.playing) {
       audioPlayers.forEach((audioPlayer) => audioPlayer.stop());
    } else {
       audioPlayers.forEach((audioPlayer) => audioPlayer.play());
    }
}
```

Dont forget to dispose every audioPlayer controller to prevent memory leaks:

```
audioPlayers.forEach((audioPlayer) => audioPlayer.dispose());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 AudioPlayer.players.forEach((key, value) {
      value.stop();
    });
```

when you play another audio you need to call this code before

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).